# Android Miracast Protocol Source Code

Tags: android

I'm researching about Miracast Protocol. Currently on Network, I cannot found clearly spec about this protocol (so I can use it to send and receive signal from Miracast-enable program).

I see that Android (above 4.2) has this feature and abstract by using `MediaRouter` class. I want to see, how Android really implement this protocol. (recogize, sending, receive ...) by view its source, but don't know where it is in Android Source Code.

Please tell me source code that Android implement Miracast Protocol.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the code is, at least partially (haven't tried it) available in AOSP : 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/media/libstagefright/wifi-display/

You may also want to have a look at this guys work, who has studied and documented Miracast implementation on Android, and even provided patches to enable it on older devices :

https://github.com/kensuke/How-to-Miracast-on-AOSP/wiki

Comment: thanks :) the only thing that i feel relative is all of them put inside wifi-display directory. When I view source code, because it contains no comment, and I hardly to recognize does this relate to miracast or not.

Comment: So, did you see that those code relates to miracast protocol ? if yes, can you tell me more clearly, where main code (for example : create miracast packet, send action ...) thanks :)

Comment: Well, given wifi-display is the 'technical' name for miracast (marketing / certification name) , I think it's pretty safe to assume this code relates to miracast implementation :)

Comment: You may also want to look at openwfd, an (in progress) open source implementation of wifi display : http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/openwfd/

Comment: thanks :) as I google, maybe this currently is a only open source of Wifi Direct Implementation and is under developmented :)

Comment: The first sentence of the presnetation states "OpenWFD is an Open-Source implementation of the Wifi-Display standard". So it's not wifi direct only, and yes it is under development (and I'm not part of it, to be clear). But wifi display is based on wifi direct, maybe this got you confused ?

Comment: I am looking for running miracast on a mac. no interesting links available. commenting here to get notifications about further progress.

Comment: OSX's getting as closed as some playware, anyway just for the records the latest shiniest and still developed miracast daemons are [MiracleCast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) and if really any Intel's [WDS](https://github.com/intel/wds)